# Rails SQL commands got error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have some tables: users, posts, translations, vocabularies
a user can create posts, make translations for words on posts and can mark translations of others as vocabularies for review. table vocabularies only has 2 columns (user_id,translation_id)
In controller I declare variable:

```
@translations = @post.translations.where("translations.words=?", params[:words], params[:end]).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabularies ON vocabularies.translation_id = translations.id AND vocabularies.user_id = 6").select("translations.*")
```

And get errors

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(translations.*) FROM "translations" LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabularies ON vocabularies.translation_id = translations.id AND vocabularies.user_id = 6 WHERE "translations"."post_id" = ? AND (translations.words='hello')
```

One more question, because the :translations and :vocabularies both have the same column user_id, so how can alias user_id of :vocabularies as learner_id?
I tried to run this command but it still got error: SQLite3::SQLException: near "as":

```
@translations = @post.translations.where("translations.words=?", params[:words], params[:end]).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabularies ON vocabularies.translation_id = translations.id AND vocabularies.user_id = 6").select("translations.*, vocabularies.user_id as learner_id")
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can reduce the query to something like this `@post.translations.joins(:vocabularies).where(words: params[:words] + params[:end], vocabularies: {user_id: 6})` and add the select at the end

Comment: I think I'm OK with joins command but I had trouble with select commands, it got error **SQLException: near "*": syntax error**

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct your `where` statement like:

```
where("translations.words = ? OR translations.words = ?", params[:words], params[:end])
```

So your query will become:

```
@translations = @post.translations.where("translations.words = ? OR translations.words = ?", params[:words], params[:end]).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabularies ON vocabularies.translation_id = translations.id AND vocabularies.user_id = 6").select("translations.*, vocabularies.user_id learner_id")
```

Comment: I changed but it get errors **SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error** `@post.translations.joins(:vocabularies).where("translations.start=? AND translations.end=?", params[:start], params[:end]).select("translations.*","vocabularies.user_id AS learner_id")`

Comment: Dear RAJ, I tried both, even with `select("translations.*")` and it still got error `SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(translations.*, vocabularies.user_id learner_id)`

Comment: everything was fine until I add `select` command, it works with `.select("translations.id")` but fails with `.select("translations.*")

Comment: Well, I think the problem is **when i add an option .select(), it refers to COUNT() command in SQL**

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems to be an error because after that, I add a command `@translations.any?` and if I remove this, everything works perfect, thanks for helping me